# Select which DbContext to automatically migrate on startup

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a small reusable package för .NET Core applications that will help with automatic migrations on application startup.

It will basically run [`Database.Migrate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime) on every `DbContext`.

But the thing here is that I only want to run it on DbContexts that has been "marked" for auto-migration. I'm thinking that I could extend [`AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection), and somehow tell the `IServiceCollection` to keep track of the particular `DbContext`. Something like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextWithMigration<TContext>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = null, ServiceLifetime contextLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped) where TContext : DbContext
{
    //TODO: Somehow remember that this DbContext should be migrated.
    return serviceCollection.AddDbContext<TContext, TContext>(optionsAction, contextLifetime, optionsLifetime);
}
```

Usage:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextWithMigration<DbContext1>();
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext2>();
    services.AddDbContextWithMigration<DbContext3>();
}
```

Then I thought that I either could use [`IStartupFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartupfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or create an extensionmethod for `IApplicationBuilder`.

With extensionmethod:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder RunMigrations(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (app == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));

    var contexts = app.ApplicationServices.GetService();
    foreach (DbContext context in contexts)
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }

    return app;
}
```

With IStartupFilter:

```
public class MigrationsFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            var contexts = builder.ApplicationServices.GetService();
            foreach (DbContext context in contexts)
            {
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }

            next(builder);
        };
    }
}
```

So I basically have two questions.

1. How can I keep track of which DbContexts that should be migrated?
2. Is this a "correct" usage of `IStartupFilter`?

Comment: I guess you have lots of options. Maybe you could create a `UseMigrations` attribute to put on the contexts you want migrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by registering a wrapper-class (`IContextMigrator`) for my migrations.

First, my extension methods:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder RunMigrations(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (app == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));


    IEnumerable<IContextMigrator> migrations = app.ApplicationServices.GetServices<IContextMigrator>();

    foreach (IContextMigrator migration in migrations)
    {
        migration.Migrate();
        // Other logic for dispose...
    }

    return app;
}


public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextWithMigration<TContext>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = null, ServiceLifetime contextLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped) where TContext : DbContext
{
    // By simply registering a transient of a wrapper-class I can resolve it later.
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IContextMigrator, ContextMigrator<TContext>>();
    return serviceCollection.AddDbContext<TContext, TContext>(optionsAction, contextLifetime, optionsLifetime);
}
```

Then my class for actually migrating:

```
public interface IContextMigrator : IDisposable
{
    void Migrate();
}

/// <summary>
/// Class responsible for migration of a DbContext.
/// Used by ApplicationBuilderExtensions to perform migrations.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
internal sealed class ContextMigrator<T> : IContextMigrator
    where T : DbContext
{
    private readonly T context;

    public ContextMigrator(T context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Migrate()
    {
        try
        {
            this.context.Database.Migrate();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new MigrationException(context.GetType().Name, e);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```